# Android ClickListeners not firing from a PopupWindow

Tags: android, onclicklistener, popupwindow

I've got a popupWindow that is triggered from the Activity Bar in Main Event. The buttons in the popup window are not triggering their respective listeners in showPopup(). Much of this popupWindow structure works fine when initiated from a fragment.  I cannot identify the root cause of this. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private final static String TAB_KEY_INDEX = "TAB_KEY";
public static Context appContext;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    appContext = getApplicationContext();
    //put Actionbar in tab mode     
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);            
    //set titles for tabs
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    //create instances of each of the fragments
    Fragment tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
    //attach those fragment instances to their respective tabs
    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(tab1Fragment));
    //add each tab to the ActionBar
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    if (savedInstanceState == null){//...do nothing                     
    }else if (savedInstanceState != null){
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX,0));
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_popup:
            showPopup();
            return true;
    }return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}   
private void showPopup() { 
    Button btnDismiss, btnSaveRecord;
    try { 
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 580, 500, true); 
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 40);

    btnDismiss=(Button)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnSaveRecord=(Button)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
    btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            saveRecord();
        }
    });
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    }
public void saveRecord(){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Event saveRecord() triggered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
}
}
```

Here's popup_layout.xml per request. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/customborder"> 
<TableRow>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is Fragment3" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>  
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Species:" />
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/textboxSpeciesxml"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                    android:layout_span="3"
        android:text="(table is empty)"/> 

  </TableRow> 

    <TableRow>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAVE" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdateRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UPDATE" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDeleteRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DELETE" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClearFormxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLEAR" />
         </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFirstRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pszFirstRecordButton"/>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPreviousRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pszPreviousRecordButton"/>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNextRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pszNextRecordButton"/>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLastRecordxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pszLastRecordButton"/>
         </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPurgeTablexml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Purge Table!" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDismissxml"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="Dismiss" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Are `btnDismissxml` and `btnSaveRecordxml` your buttons in popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `btnDismissxml` and `btnSaveRecordxml` are your buttons in popup window, you could find them using `layout.findViewById` rather than `MainActivity.this.findViewById`. Use the following code:

```
View layout = (TableLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
// ...

btnDismiss=(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    // ...
});
btnSaveRecord=(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: @portsample please add the `xml` of your popup layout

Comment: @portsample the answer was edited. please cast your layout as `TableLayout` and let me know the result